# elif error in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started python a couple of days back..now learning to use 'if' and 'elif'...created a basic program....when I use elif, it shows me

> syntax error:invalid syntax

```
print('welcome to my calculator')
num1 = int(input('enter the first number:'))
num2 = int(input('enter the second number:'))
print('select options')
functions = ['Add','Sub','Mul','Div']
print (functions)
options = input("enter the desired option:")
if options == 'Add':
    print(num1+num2)
print('num1+num2=', num1+num2) 
elif options == 'Sub':
    print(num1-num2)
print('num1-num2=', (num1-num2))
```

when I ran this, I got the following error

```
elif options == 'Sub':
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone help me solve this error?

Comment: `print('num1+num2=', num1+num2) ` line should be indented the same way as the line above it

Comment: you might have indented one line with `spaces` and the other line with `tab`. change both to the `tab` or both `space`

Comment: THANK U SO MUCH FOR UR KIND AND FAST RESPONSE....I GOT IT DONE ....:)

Answer (score 1):

For python you need to have everything inside of your if, elif and else at the same indention. Change it to

```
if options == 'Add':
    print(num1+num2)
    print('num1+num2', num1+num2)
elif options == 'Sub':
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print('welcome to my calculator')
num1 = int(input('enter the first number:'))
num2 = int(input('enter the second number:'))
print('select options')
functions = ['Add','Sub','Mul','Div']
print (functions)
options = input("enter the desired option:")
if options == 'Add':
    print(num1+num2)
    print('num1+num2=', num1+num2) 
elif options == 'Sub':
    print(num1-num2)
    print('num1-num2=', (num1-num2))
else:                    # you need this line as well
    print("continue... remaining logic")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your script is in the indetention. Basically, in order to fix the problem, you should change your code in this way:

```
options = input("enter the desired option:")
if options == 'Add':
    print(num1+num2)
    print('num1+num2=', num1+num2) 
elif options == 'Sub':
    print(num1-num2)
    print('num1-num2=', (num1-num2))
```

In your code, the line `print('num1+num2=', num1+num2)` ended the `if` statement, and so `elif` doesn't have any meaning

Answer (score 0):

Put the "prints" inside the "if" statements and that's it.
It worked for me:

```
welcome to my calculator
enter the first number:3
enter the second number:2
select options
['Add', 'Sub', 'Mul', 'Div']
enter the desired option:Sub
1
num1-num2= 1
```

Tried also the 'Add' option.